# IIS URL Rewrite not working after first forward slash, but URL forward works fine

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

So if I enter a url like: http://sample.com/maindir/test123 my Rewrite works fine. If I enter a url like: http://sample.com/maindir/test123/test234 it breaks, giving a 500 error. Both of these work if I change it to a redirect instead of rewrite rule

```xml
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^maindir\/?(?:([^\/]+))?\/?(?:([^\/]+))?\/?(?:([^\/]+))?\/?(?:([^\/]+))?\/?" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="maindir/?a1[]={R:1}&amp;a1[]={R:2}&amp;a1[]={R:3}&amp;a1[]={R:4}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

After much frustration with this, trying to find a solution, I figured I would see if anyone else can see what's going on here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the details of the 500 error?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be showing any information in the 500 error.

Comment: Have you tried if the rewritten url `http://sample.com/maindir/?a1[]=test123&a1[]=test234&a1[]=&a1[]=` actually works? Do you also pass a query string by any chance?